# Rename [msdnsubscriptions] to [msdn-subscription]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tag [msdnsubscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msdnsubscriptions) without a dash makes much less sense to me than more readable [msdn-subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msdn-subscriptions) or singular [msdn-subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msdn-subscription).

Comment: Is this tag even appropriate?  Most of the questions that are asked under it appear to be about licensing or product keys; both are off-topic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's another question and I agree with you. Can we ban tags? I'd do this with all 4: msdns, msdnss, msdn-s, msdn-ss.

Comment: Not really.  Blacklisting is reserved only for the most egregious tags.  Tags with zero questions get removed during the nightly batch.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: So does it make sense to untag those questions from this tag? So it will be removed next night.

Comment: Yep.  I did a few, but don't have time to do them all.  I closed some of them.

Comment: @Robert: I thought it can be done programmatically. If not, I can participate too. Untag or flag or vote, etc.

Comment: Actually, I'm retracting my close vote. This isn't a cleanup issue as the other tags don't exist.

Comment: @Robert, I did the rest. This tag is awful. As is many of the questions in [licensing] and in [bizspark]. Unfortunately, many of the older questions would have become untagged (which I can't do), so [msdn] was the lucky recepient. Close votes were applied where merited. SO was a scary place in 2009/2010.

Comment: @jmac: Can you post your comment as an answer please? I'll accept it.

Comment: @VadimKotov: I don't see any questions neither under [tag:msdn-subscription] nor [tag:msdn-subscriptions]. Do you know what was the final outcome?

Comment: @abatishchev Looks like all tags were removed, see [jmac's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250906/1000551)- "Following Robert Harvey's lead I removed the tag. It should be auto-removed as it now has zero questions". This request was marked as completed by mod.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of all the questions I read with the tag, not a single one had to do with programming related to msdn subscriptions, but rather licensing questions related to software obtained through msdn subscriptions (or that can be obtained through msdn subscriptions). [Following Robert Harvey's lead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225924/rename-msdnsubscriptions-to-msdn-subscription#comment738861_225924) I removed the tag. It should be auto-removed as [it now has zero questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msdnsubscriptions).

Answer (score 2):

I agree. It should be [msdn-subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msdn-subscriptions), which matches its name - *MSDN Subscriptions* - and our convention of hyphenating spaces.

We shouldn't use the singular form ([msdn-subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msdn-subscription)) since this is an actual product being asked about, and the product takes the plural form for its name.

Comment: It should not exist. It is an abomination. So many questions asking for interpretation of terms of service, and other licensing-related issues, no real programming-related questions.

Comment: Very well! I didn't look that closely at its actual content. Glad to see you burninated it then, considering.

Comment: If by 'burninated it' you mean 'edited a lot of really old posts to remove it', then yes. Better me than you. Digging in to posts from 2009/2010 is really not fun.

Comment: That's burnination in a nutshell, yeah. I've done the same before.